# Properties of the divisor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ , $q$ and $s$ be integers such that $p^2 = s\cdot q^2$. Then it follows that

$a$.) $p$ is an even number

$b$.) if $s$ divides $p$, then $s$ is a perfect square;

$c$.) $s$ divides $p$ ;

$d$.) $q^2$ divides $p$

I could figure out that first option is incorrect by finding out an example which proved it wrong. Similarly I could rule out option $4$ as well. Option $c$ is definitely right. Since we know that $\frac{p^2}{s}$=$q^2$ which is an integer.
Then it divides $p^2$ then it must divide $p$ as well.However, I am unable to check for the second option .

Comment: c) is not true: if $s$ divides $p^2$, it doesn't have to divide $p$. Example: take $s=p^2$ and $q=1$. b) is a weird statement, but it's true because $s$ must be a perfect square regardless of whether it divides $p$.

Comment: $s$ is a perfect square, no matter what. So 'b' is actually correct. If two numbers multiply upto a number which is a perfect square and one of them is a square then the other one is a square too. Consider this, we know that if we prime factorize a square, each appears in a multiple of 2. That means that there are is an even number of any prime factor whichever it is. If we take $s >= 1$, then the set containing prime factors if p $\subset$ of set containing prime factors of q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b)$ is true regardless whether $s$ divides $p$ or not. Taking square root both sides you have: $p = q\sqrt{s}$. Now if $s$ is not a perfect square, then $\sqrt{s} \notin \mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow p \notin \mathbb{Q}$, a contradiction since $p \in \mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Q}$. Thus $s$ must be a perfect square.